# Why this int to hex conversion in this function is an invalid?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a RDT2.2 client-server model in python, the packet I am sending is an array so that the binary values read from the data file does not get messed up when the server writes it back. This is the function that calculates the checksum for the packet. I am getting this error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '00-1'

```
def calcChecksum(packet, size):
    checksum = 0
    index = 0
    sizeworked = size

    while (size > 1):
        checksum += int((str("%02x" % (packet[index],)) +
                         str("%02x" % (packet[index+1],))), 16)
        sizeworked -= 2
        index += 2

    if size:
       checksum += packet[index]

    checksum = (checksum >> 16) + (checksum & 0xFFFF)
    checksum += (checksum >> 16)
    return (~checksum) & 0xFFFF
```

The checksum function is called by this make packet function.

```
def makePacket(data, datasize, num):
    packet = array('b')
    if (data == 0):
        packet.append(0)
    else:
        packet.fromfile(data, datasize)
    print len(packet)
    packet.append(num)
    print len(packet)
    checksum = calcChecksum(packet, len(packet)) #here
    packet.append(checksum)
    print len(packet)
    return packet
```

Is the error I am getting because I am using an array instead of a list? I modified some code that was based on a user made list rather than data read from a binary data file.

Comment: Why do you want to go from integers to string to integers? Why not just combine the integers as usual by shifting and adding to produce a 16bit value?

Comment: The error message says that you have a `-` character in the middle of your hex number.

Comment: I think the problem is that `packet[index+1]` contains the number `-1`.

Comment: The problem I am having is that I'm not sure how to convert the raw binary data read in from the file to a value that I can do the ones complement checksum. I found this code that looked that it was using the correct algorithm. I know that python stores the binary from a file as a string.

Comment: This question could really use a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.  It especially needs some sample data to allow us to run your code.